# ReCaptcha returns valid regardless of host matching key

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, recaptcha

I hope someone can cure my ignorance. I have encountered the following problem before and I can't seem to understand why it is happening.

I'm working on a project that has two web fronts running under different addresses, which are essentially pointing to different directories under the same ASP.Net MVC2 project witch different master pages.

Now I've created 3 sets of key pairs, one for *localhost*, one for *site1*, and one for *site2*, thinking ReCaptcha will only tell me the challenge is good, if it comes from the appropriate host with the matching keys (and if I answer correctly ofc.).

The reality is no matter which keys I set up, be it localhost or otherwise, the response is always positive.

Note that I've only tried this on my puny little home PC as a test project, so I don't know if things would go down differently once deployed to the production environment.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need separate keys for each website.  I use the same keys on localhost and my live site and haven't had any trouble.

I'd suggest just use the one set of keys, and just try getting it up and running with one website.  It *does* work, I've been using it for about 2 years.

Failing that show us your code :)